# Input XML which has EventType != 'HardBounce' should be copied to output

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Interaction>
        <RecipientId>666994250005</RecipientId>
        <RecipientType>Normal</RecipientType>
        <MailingId>18744460</MailingId>
        <ReportId>2121196700</ReportId>
        <CampaignId/>
        <Email>ilovepizza@mntest.net</Email>
        <EventType>HardBounce</EventType>
        <EventTimestamp>05/11/202113:46:40</EventTimestamp>
        <BodyType/>
        <ContentId/>
        <ClickName/>
        <URL/>
        <ConversionAction/>
        <ConversionDetail/>
        <ConversionAmount/>
        <SuppressionReason/>
        <MailingName>YourNovemberTrend-TESTING_682-BOUNCES</MailingName>
        <MailingSubject>YourNovemberTrend-TESTING_682-BOUNCES</MailingSubject>
        <CONTACT_MC_ID>42010A0351251EEBA0EF17B38C3EDC78</CONTACT_MC_ID>
        <CAMPAIGN_ID>0000000682</CAMPAIGN_ID>
        <SOURCE_OBJECT_ID>C01AFE8349D7F713787E25B656A3D2D6BA205205</SOURCE_OBJECT_ID>
        <UUID>ca69251e-8b0e-1d90-1700-1c42c1610f6d</UUID>
    </Interaction>
    <Interaction>
        <RecipientId>672386985145</RecipientId>
        <RecipientType>Normal</RecipientType>
        <MailingId>18848768</MailingId>
        <ReportId>2141674081</ReportId>
        <CampaignId/>
        <Email>cg@gmail.com</Email>
        <EventType>Sent</EventType>
        <EventTimestamp>06/08/202119:28:06</EventTimestamp>
        <BodyType/>
        <ContentId/>
        <ClickName/>
        <URL/>
        <ConversionAction/>
        <ConversionDetail/>
        <ConversionAmount/>
        <SuppressionReason/>
        <MailingName>TrendEmailTestSend425(18)</MailingName>
        <MailingSubject>TESTING:YourNovemberTrend-710Campaign</MailingSubject>
        <CONTACT_MC_ID>42010A0351251EDBA6904634DF983CB0</CONTACT_MC_ID>
        <CAMPAIGN_ID>0000000710</CAMPAIGN_ID>
        <SOURCE_OBJECT_ID>42948F6B87172477E4BE993B3EC48255EF4A27D4</SOURCE_OBJECT_ID>
        <UUID>1292721e-8b0e-1d90-1700-1c42c1610f6d</UUID>
    </Interaction>
</root>
```

I am trying below XSLT but it's not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/root/Interaction">
        <xsl:if test="/root/Interaction/EventType/text() != 'HardBounce'">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output Expected is:

```
<root>
     <Interaction>
        <RecipientId>672386985145</RecipientId>
        <RecipientType>Normal</RecipientType>
        <MailingId>18848768</MailingId>
        <ReportId>2141674081</ReportId>
        <CampaignId/>
        <Email>cg@gmail.com</Email>
        <EventType>Sent</EventType>
        <EventTimestamp>06/08/202119:28:06</EventTimestamp>
        <BodyType/>
        <ContentId/>
        <ClickName/>
        <URL/>
        <ConversionAction/>
        <ConversionDetail/>
        <ConversionAmount/>
        <SuppressionReason/>
        <MailingName>TrendEmailTestSend425(18)</MailingName>
        <MailingSubject>TESTING:YourNovemberTrend-710Campaign</MailingSubject>
        <CONTACT_MC_ID>42010A0351251EDBA6904634DF983CB0</CONTACT_MC_ID>
        <CAMPAIGN_ID>0000000710</CAMPAIGN_ID>
        <SOURCE_OBJECT_ID>42948F6B87172477E4BE993B3EC48255EF4A27D4</SOURCE_OBJECT_ID>
        <UUID>1292721e-8b0e-1d90-1700-1c42c1610f6d</UUID>
    </Interaction>
</root>
```

Just dipping toe in XSLT. Thanks for help.
The node should be copied to target on meeting the condition.

Do not Read below. This is just to get the stack over
StackoverStackoverflow is asking me to put more details to question but i think i have provided enough details to comprehend the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction:

```
<xsl:template match="/root/Interaction">
```

puts you in the context of `Interaction`. From this context, the test of `EventType` needs to use the relative path to the `EventType` that is the child of the current `Interaction` - e.g.

```
<xsl:if test="EventType != 'HardBounce'">
```

What you have starts from the root and tests if there is at least one `EventType` that meets the condition in the entire XML document. This is of course true for **all** `Interaction` elements being tested.

---

Note that you could accomplish the same thing much more simply by:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Interaction[EventType != 'HardBounce']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Block the elements you don't want from being copied with an empty template `<xsl:template match="Interaction[EventType = 'HardBounce']"/>`. Handle the rest through your first template or even replace it by declaring `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`, if you are using XSLT 3.